# loading dplyr after plyr is causing issues

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

Test Case:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
mtcars%>%rename(x=gear)
```

This gives error. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As above, or restart R session, then load dplyr first. Consider using ddplyer or other newer versions that play together better

Comment: You can also access a specific package by including the package name in the function call. For example, even if you load `plyr` after `dplyr`, you can do `mtcars %>% dplyr::rename(x=gear)` to use `dplyr`'s `rename` function. However, it's generally better to load `plyr` before `dplyr` (assuming you want to use functions from both packages), since `dplyr` is faster. Or, you can just load `dplyr` and then use, for example, `plyr::rename` if you want a specific `plyr` function that's masked by `dplyr`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The issue is that this is part of a large codebase with multiple developers. So detaching may not be practical.

Comment: @nongkrong it's never a good idea to use `detach()`

Comment: @nongkrong I don't do that ;)

Answer (score 12):

Based on @hadley's tweet. Best answer is to load plyr ALWAYS before dplyr, AND not load plyr again. Pasting his tweet for reference.

---

```
Hadley Wickham ‏@hadleywickham  Jul 27
@gunapemmaraju just load plyr before dplyr?
```

Comment: I think you mean `and not load dplyr again`

Answer (score 5):

I have this  problem when require plyr again sourcing files.
You can do

```
if("dplyr" %in% (.packages())){
          detach("package:dplyr", unload=TRUE) 
          detach("package:plyr", unload=TRUE) 
} 
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
```

Comment: Wow I tried unloading and loading again manually in every different order but it wasn't working, but this code fixed my problem! Thank you!