# Count in plyr not working, returns "wrong result size (3), expected 8 or 1"

Tags: r, count, plyr

Sorry, I know there are lots of 'count' questions already - I'm trying to to return the frequency of occurrence of unique rows a data frame. I'm found lots of solutions suggesting 'count' in the plyr package, but I can't find anything with this error. I've trying to reproduce an example given in another question:

```
> df = data.frame(x1=c(0,1,1,1,2,3,3,3),
            x2=c(0,1,1,3,2,3,3,2),
            x3=c(0,1,1,1,2,3,3,2))

> count(df, vars = c("x1", "x2", "x3"))
```

but this returns the following error:

```
Error: wrong result size (3), expected 8 or 1
```

I get the same thing with my own data. I've also tried a different example:

```
> bevs <- data.frame(cbind(name = c("Bill", "Llib"), drink = c("coffee", "tea", "cocoa", "water"), cost = seq(1:8)))
> bevs$cost <- as.integer(bevs$cost)
> bevs

name  drink cost
1 Bill coffee    1
2 Llib    tea    2
3 Bill  cocoa    3
4 Llib  water    4
5 Bill coffee    5
6 Llib    tea    6
7 Bill  cocoa    7
8 Llib  water    8

> count(bevs, "name")
```

this just returns the number of rows, not the number of unique rows per name.

```
Source: local data frame [1 x 2]

"name"     n
(chr) (int)
1   name     8
```

I'm copying the example code exactly, so I'm not sure what's going on......any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative using `dplyr`:

`df %>% count_(names(.))` or `df %>% count(x1, x2, x3)`

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
#Groups: x1, x2 [?]
#
#     x1    x2    x3     n
#  (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (int)
#1     0     0     0     1
#2     1     1     1     2
#3     1     3     1     1
#4     2     2     2     1
#5     3     2     2     1
#6     3     3     3     2
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you've loaded `dplyr` after `plyr` ([more there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644739/loading-dplyr-after-plyr-is-causing-issues)). Try the following: `plyr::count(df, vars = c("x1", "x2", "x3"))` and `plyr::count(bevs, "name")`.

Comment: he... or _she_! in that case I think all columns would be included and the session would have to be restarted or packages detached.

Comment: I see, yes you are right. I'd lost track of when / what I'd loaded trying the different options but restarting and just loading plyr made the original code work (subsequently loading dplyr made your suggested code work). All sorted. Thank you!