# Have to call dplyr:: before dplyr functions to get correct output

Tags: r, dplyr

When aggregating data with `summarise` the `group_by` function from the line before is often being ignored. I can solve this problem by calling `dplyr::` before the function, but this problem is nevertheless counter-intuitive and problematic. Here is an example of what is happening:

```
df <- data.frame(grp = c("a", "a", "b", "b"),
                 value = c( 1:4))

> df %>% group_by(grp) %>%
+   summarise(value = mean(value))
  value
1   2.5
> df %>% group_by(grp) %>%
+   dplyr::summarise(value = mean(value))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  grp   value
  <fct> <dbl>
1 a       1.5
2 b       3.5
```

I've read that loading `plyr` after `dplyr` can sometimes lead to this problem - and after not loading `plyr` at all anymore I get this unwanted behavior less often.

I'm using `R` version `3.6.1` on Windows 10 x64 and `dplyr` version `0.8.3`.

**Session Info**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] lazyeval_0.2.2        data.table_1.12.2     shinythemes_1.1.2     shinycssloaders_0.2.0 plyr_1.8.4           
 [6] plotly_4.9.0          shiny_1.3.2           dplyr_0.8.3           mgcv_1.8-28           nlme_3.1-140         
[11] kableExtra_1.1.0      scales_1.0.0          readxl_1.3.1          tidyr_0.8.3           knitr_1.23           
[16] lubridate_1.7.4       ggplot2_3.2.0         reshape2_1.4.3        rlang_0.4.0           DT_0.7               
[21] tibble_2.1.3          qlcMatrix_0.9.7       sparsesvd_0.2         slam_0.1-45           Matrix_1.2-17        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.4.0         jsonlite_1.6       viridisLite_0.3.0  splines_3.6.1      assertthat_0.2.1   highr_0.8         
 [7] cellranger_1.1.0   yaml_2.2.0         pillar_1.4.2       backports_1.1.4    lattice_0.20-38    glue_1.3.1        
[13] digest_0.6.20      RColorBrewer_1.1-2 promises_1.0.1     rvest_0.3.4        colorspace_1.4-1   htmltools_0.3.6   
[19] httpuv_1.5.1       pkgconfig_2.0.2    purrr_0.3.2        xtable_1.8-4       webshot_0.5.1      later_0.8.0       
[25] docopt_0.6.1       withr_2.1.2        cli_1.1.0          magrittr_1.5       crayon_1.3.4       mime_0.7          
[31] evaluate_0.14      fansi_0.4.0        xml2_1.2.1         tools_3.6.1        hms_0.5.0          stringr_1.4.0     
[37] munsell_0.5.0      compiler_3.6.1     grid_3.6.1         rstudioapi_0.10    htmlwidgets_1.3    crosstalk_1.0.0   
[43] labeling_0.3       rmarkdown_1.14     gtable_0.3.0       R6_2.4.0           zeallot_0.1.0      utf8_1.1.4        
[49] readr_1.3.1        stringi_1.4.3      Rcpp_1.0.2         vctrs_0.2.0        tidyselect_0.2.5   xfun_0.8
```

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to the comment from `@r2evans`, I ran this line of code to see which package was loading `plyr`, unbeknownst to me:

```
Filter(function(p) grepl("\\bplyr\\b", packageDescription(p)$Imports), gsub("package:", "", grep("^package:", search(), value = TRUE)))
```

It turns out loading `reshape2` was also loading `plyr` - so loading `dplyr` last has resolved this issue for me.

Comment: Have you try to uninstall the ``plyr`` package and reinstall it ? Because your session info has ``plyr`` loaded. Is it possible you have setup R to automatically load the package ? My guess is that your  ``.Rprofile`` is loading ``plyr`` when R starts or something along those lines.

Comment: I've *never* seen `summarise` (or other dplyr functions) "not work sometimes" given the same data input, so this seems odd to me, Your mention of `dplyr`-before-`plyr` is the typical culprit, is the most common, and your use of the `summarise` (not `ize`) spelling avoids `Hmisc::summarize` as another potential conflict (as can be seen with `subset(help.search("summari[sz]e")$matches, grepl("^summari[sz]e$", Topic))`).

Comment: Conflicts in general can be annoying, especially when the messages during package load (that announces conflicts) whiz by and we miss or ignore them in the flurry of console activity. You can typically tell *which* version of a function you'll be calling by just typing the function name on the console: for me, `summarise` produces the function body, ending with `<environment: namespace:dplyr>` (an unambiguous indicator). If you see a different namespace, then you know what's going on.

Comment: Finding which of your currently-loaded packages is unknowingly (to you) importing the `plyr` package can be seen with this (perhaps better ways exist): `Filter(function(p) grepl("\\bplyr\\b", packageDescription(p)$Imports), gsub("package:", "", grep("^package:", search(), value = TRUE)))`. If there is anything returned, you found one of your attached packages that is bringing in `plyr`.

Comment: @Gainz I uninstalled and reinstalled `plyr` and got the same error - however it could be the case the `plyr` was being loaded because of another package - loading `dplyr` last seems to help right now.

Comment: @bjorn2bewild, which package(s) are causing `plyr` to be imported/loaded?

Comment: @bjorn2bewild Alright in that case, like r2evans is saying ``plyr`` is probably getting load by one of your package.

Comment: That is odd ... try it with `$Depends` instead of `$Imports` ... perhaps even `$LinkingTo`, though that would be odd. Also ,try `$Suggests`. (Yes, there are a lot of ways it can happen.)

Comment: @bjorn2bewild Close your R session and R studio, then open it and print the ``sessionInfo()`` once again without loading any packages please.

Comment: Ahh! Thank you @r2evans! It was `reshape2`!!

Comment: Not to change your whole workflow, but unless you know you need `reshape2`, I believe many have migrated towards `tidyr::gather` and `tidyr::spread` to replace `reshape2`'s wide/long conversions.

Comment: Good point @r2evans - it's on my to-do list. Thanks for all of your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem, but finding the culprit can be problematic. Some techniques to remedy the problem:

- Knowing *which* version of the function you are trying to use is likely the first step, as it identifies which package is in conflict. This is a common problem with me with `summarize` (`dplyr`, `plyr`, and `Hmisc`), `lag` (`dplyr` and `stats`), and less-often `filter` (same two). You can see which version you are using by either typing the function and watching the function-body scroll by, or you can just type:

  ```r
  environment(summarise)
  # <environment: namespace:dplyr>
  ```
- Sometimes, the package load was just bad-luck timing based on trying new code, attempting branches of analysis, etc ... and something that is in the search path just isn't needed anymore. Finding this culprit can be annoying, but if you *know* you don't need a package anymore, you can always `detach("package:___")` and try again<sup>1</sup>.
- Occasionally, just restarting the R session is sufficient. This is hampered sometimes by the auto-saving of the workspace, in that attached packages and such are restored (with conflicts still in place). So restarting to a *fresh* R session can be helpful. If you rely on the data-saving aspects of saving the workspace, then try an explicit saving of the variables you need (this can be painstaking if a lot) and reloading just those variables ...
- If none of the above works (or you don't want to restart R), you can find which of your currently-loaded packages are causing the culprit-conflict by doing something like this:

  ```r
  Filter(function(p) any(grepl("\\bplyr\\b", packageDescription(p)[c("Imports","Depends","Suggests","LinkingTo")])),
         gsub("package:", "", grep("^package:", search(), value = TRUE)))
  ```

  If nothing currently in the `search()` path (of packages ... not directories of executables) has "legitimately"<sup>2</sup> caused the import of your conflict-causing package, then you'll see `character(0)` ... otherwise, you'll see the packages to blame.
- From here, the order that packages are loaded is key: whichever is loaded *last* wins: think about loading packages as adding layers on top of each other: the one that is on top is the version that you will see. You can *always* access the version of a conflicted package directly with the double-colon notation (e.g., `dplyr::lag` instead of just `lag`), and in fact that is often the preferred method to reference non-base packages when writing your own package. (It is not always required, but its verbosity can be both declarative and unambiguous.)

Notes:

1. Some packages do not `detach` well, often due to DLL loading. You can try `detach(..., force=TRUE)`, but sometimes the safest way is to just restart R.
2. it is always possible to cause the loading of another package from functions, even if the `DESCRIPTION` file does not mention this act. I believe CRAN is pretty good about catching and preventing this behavior, but side-loading packages (e.g., from GitHub) can easily bypass this safety feature.
3. The conflicts between `dplyr` and `plyr` have been known for years (e.g., https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/347 from 2014, and [loading dplyr after plyr is causing issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31644739/3358272) from 2015). That is why [the `plyr` warning in `dplyr`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/a4980700383ada4e4f0eb39e501105d9e261ec0a/R/zzz.r#L15-L23) was added to `dplyr` startup messages in 2014.