# How to filter column and then calculate means of the filtered column?

Tags: r

I am trying to compute the mean amount spent on wine by education level. When I go to filter the data I do this:

```
marketing %>%
select(Education, MntWines) %>%
group_by(Education) %>%
summarise(MntWines_mean= mean(MntWines))
```

And I get this output[a 1x1 table with just MntWines mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dka33.png)

How do I get the means for each output?

Comment: Can you share some sample data, so that we can check what is happening?

Comment: My guess is that you are inadvertently using `plyr::summarise` instead of `dplyr::summarise`. To verify, type `summarise` and confirm whether it ends with `namespace:plyr` or `namespace:dplyr`. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31644739/3358272 and https://krlmlr.github.io/pdlyr/vignettes/pdlyr.html.

Comment: The _fix_: in the short term, use `%>% dplyr::summarise(...)`; in the long term, load plyr first (or not at all).